# Bootstrap elements container class causes another bootstrap element to change

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a footer and I have a container for the content in the page. But the content "container" class in a div causes the footer to be applied in that container too for some reason. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<section id="products" class="products py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <!--Section Title-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-sm-6 text-center">
                <h1 class="text-capitalize product-title" id="promosyonHeader">
                    Promosyon Ürünlerimiz
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Footer HTML:

```
<!--Footer-->
<footer class="footer mt-5">
    <div class="text-center py-5 border-top border-secondary">
    <h2 class="py-1">Doğuhan Tanıtım</h2>
    <div class="mx-auto heading-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="footer" class="row mb-0">
            <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 text-center">
                <p>İskitler/Ankara</p>
                <p>number</p>
                <p>com.tr</p>
                <div class="justify-content-center">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="copyright text-center py-3 border-top text-light" id="tm"><p>Tanıtım &trade;</p></div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your footer you are putting a container in a container, why ? Please provide whole example to be able to help you correctly

Comment: @MaxiGui I think it was just a mistake but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: please share your css and whole example page

Comment: I think you just forgot to paste part of the code but I noticed you don't have the closing </section> and </div> tags, that would mean that the footer ends up inside the section

Comment: Please provide all relevant, reproducible code

Comment: @JonasGrumann Yes! it was just a simple section and div closing mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="products" class="products py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <!--Section Title-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <h1 class="text-capitalize product-title" id="promosyonHeader">
                        Promosyon Ürünlerimiz
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <footer class="footer mt-5">
        <div class="text-center py-5 border-top border-secondary">
            <h2 class="py-1">Doğuhan Tanıtım</h2>
            <div class="mx-auto heading-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="footer" class="row mb-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 text-center">
                        <p>İskitler/Ankara</p>
                        <p>number</p>
                        <p>com.tr</p>
                        <div class="justify-content-center">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

I think there is problem with your bootstrap version. or you forgot closing some tags

Comment: Yes! I just forgot to close a div and a section tag :). Thanks a lot